# Java json response shows date in numeric value

Tags: java, json, date-format

```
@Data
public class Reponse {

    private String event;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date eventDate;

    private Double amount;
}
```

Json response is like

```
{ 
  event: "transcation',
  eventDate: 1213123434,
  amount: 100
}
```

Here, eventDate is showing numeric value 1540317600000 instead of 2018-10-23

Comment: The number 1540317600000 is milliseconds since the Unix epoch (equal to Tuesday 23. October 2018 18:00:00 GMT according to https://www.epochconverter.com, please try yourself). What’s the problem? Does the client object to the response? Have you got a requirement for what the event date should look like in the response, and if so, how?

Comment: How are you serializing the response to JSON? Are you using Jackson, gson or some other library? Please tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can annotated the field with `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")`. Then, response time format will be like "`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`"

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;


public class Reponse {

    private String event;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    private Date eventDate;

    private Double amount;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use Spring boot 2.x instead 1.x ,the default behavior has changed
add `spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=true` to your configuration to return to the previous behavior
[Spring Boot 2.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#jackson--json-support)

Answer (score 1):

spring 2.x flipped a Jackson configuration default to write JSR-310 dates as ISO-8601 strings. If you wish to return to the previous behavior, you can add

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=true
```

to your application-context configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

```
I suppose you are using rest framework such as spring boot or jersey which in turn 
converts your java date into epoch format before sending it to the client. So while 
sending response you can format you date into the format you want. Please refer 
the code below.

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
sdf.setLenient(false);
String responseDate = sdf.format(date);
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.